# Application launching

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nswindow

When I firstly created a window based application (with using coredata), I not seen

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)
```

notice method. Then I added this method into delegate(delegate inherits from `NSObject`), but method is not calls. I wants to customize window loading and make window loading not from name in pList.

**How I can do it** ? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement NSApplicationDelegate as well

Comment: May be NSApplicationDelegate?

Comment: Yeah my bad i thought it was iPhone

Comment: Hm... I did implement application delegate
@interface myapp_AppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
But method applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification)aNotification isn't calls:(

Comment: Make sure there is a connection from File's Owner to your delegate class in MainMenu.xib.

Comment: wah! App delegate depends on the window?o_O
Thanks:)
I just novice in MacOs development after iOS:)